# google.protobuf.Struct is coming back as just fields in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-node, grpc-js

I have the following response message in my proto file via NodeJS.

```
message WorkSpaceResponse{
    google.protobuf.Struct workspace = 1;
}
```

And below is the service function that sends back the response as:

```
    let sample = {
        "name": "Test Workspace",
        "id":"sampleId"
    }
    callback(null, { workspace: sample });
```

However, when the response gets back to the client all I'm getting is the following:

```
{
  "fields": {}
}
```

Why is it so, I was expecting the result as

```
{
  "name": "Test Workspace",
  "id":"sampleId"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's **not** very well documented but here's it documented for Google's Artifact Registry Node.JS SDK [`google.protobuf.Struct`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/artifact-registry/latest/artifact-registry/protos.google.protobuf.struct). I think you'll need to [`toObject`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/artifact-registry/latest/artifact-registry/protos.google.protobuf.struct#_google_cloud_artifact_registry_protos_google_protobuf_Struct_toObject_member_1_) the response value that you receive from the server to convert the response into a JavaScript object.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for your suggestion. However, after attempting your suggestion I was greeted with ```response.message.toObject()``` is not a function error. It's so  sad they didn't document this for NodeJS.

Comment: hey, can you please share your code here? how you apply  toObject(). kindly share the full code